# How can I make server query some data from client via grpc?

Tags: grpc

I am using `grpc` for client/server communication since it supports bidirectional streaming. I have read some doc relates to that: https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/

It supports:

- A simple RPC where the client request to server to receive a response
- A server-side streaming RPC where the client sends a request to the server and gets a stream to read a sequence of messages back.
- A client-side streaming RPC where the client writes a sequence of messages and sends them to the server, again using a provided stream

I have a case that to let server to send a query request to client to receive a response. The bi-directional is only used in streaming case not request-response case.

I couldn't find any way to support that pattern. Is this supported by grpc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initiator of a request is by definition the client.

To address your need:

1. the code currently functioning only as a gRPC server must also implement a gRPC client; and
2. the code currently functioning only as a gRPC client must also implement a gRPC server.

Comment: Will there be two websocket connection underneath? One is server -> client, the other is client -> server?

Comment: gRPC uses HTTP/2 which uses TCP. WebSocket is not used. gRPC clients communicate with gRPC servers via channels. A channel may use one or more TCP connections. A TCP connection is defined by the server's host:port; gRPC servers on multiple host:port require multiple TCP connections.

Comment: In your solution, there will be two TCP connections, one on each side?

Comment: If both gRPC servers are running and clients are holding channels open on them concurrently.